# What is the Chinese way to say "We had a lot of fun"?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I know an English sentence cannot be translated into Chinese word-by-word. So is there a idiomatic way to express the same meaning of "We had a lot of fun" in Chinese? (The context-- someone said this to a party host when he is about to leave the party: Thank you for having us. We had a lot of fun.)

The word "had" is in past tense. So the Chinese equivalent needs to indicate this too.

Comment: When you leave a party you can say to the host,谢谢你们的款待，我们今天真的玩的很嗨。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Past tenths aren't as explicitly stated a lot of times in Chinese as they are in English.

For instance, your question `We had a lot of fun` could easily be translated as:

*我们今天晚上玩得很开心*

we + tonight + play + very + happy

and (assuming that you're not going to parties during the daytime) that would be a perfectly idiomatic, grammatical sentence.

Here **玩得很开心** would be the equivalent of the English *had a lot of fun*.

Note: 玩 here would *sound* a lot better er-ized: that is to say 玩儿 and not just 玩.

Comment: Is there a more generic saying? 玩得很开心 uses degree complement with the verb 玩. But if the situation is that a student said this to the teacher after a class, 玩 is not applicable.

Comment: 上课上得很开心, you can fill it in specifically if you'd like, or 今天真开心 or 今天真好玩儿 if you want something more generalized.

Comment: The generic answer you wrote makes sense if the phrase is "had a lot of fun". Just curious, if the phrase is "have a lot of fun", how do you say it in Chinese? The context is: someone is going to a party. I say "Have a lot of fun!". 今天真开心 和 今天真好玩儿 don't sound right to me.

Comment: Have a lot of fun! 玩得开心哟！ or you can say 玩得开心点哟！